# Do I need my AppDelegate.swift to be in Objective C for PayPal SDK

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, sdk

I'm creating an iOS application in swift. The SDK for PayPal, appears to only be Objective-C, can I use the SDK in Swift or do I need to change my AppDelegate Files into the old .h and .m files?

Cheers,
Emerson

Answer (score 0):

You can import PayPal's SDK files into the bridging header to enable usage in swift files.

Comment: I do have the files imported into the bridging header, it's just for the associated keys look like they are only able to be added in obj-c.

Comment: PayPal's github does have a swift example that you could take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had gone through the process as I did, It was much easier to start a new Obj-c project.

I created the new project and imported all my files, with a few minutes set up I was able to incorporate PayPal and Parse SDKs, fully functioning.

Thank you everyone for your answers.